# skimage treshold_local does not work with pictures loaded using io.imread

Tags: scikit-image

I am was trying out one of the sample Python scripts available from the web site of Scikit Image. This script demonstrates Otsu segmentation at a local level. The script works with pictures loaded using

> data.page()

but not using

> io.imread

. Any suggestions?

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_thresholding.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-thresholding-py

**Picture file**

[image]

**Actual output - the Local thresholding window is empty**

[image]

As you can see, Global thresholding has worked.But Local Thresholding has failed to produce any results.

Strangely, if I use data.page() then everything works fine.

**Script**

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu,threshold_local
import matplotlib
from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

filename="C:\\Lenna.png"
mypic= img_as_ubyte (io.imread(filename))


#image = data.page()  #This works - why not io.imread ?
imagefromfile=io.imread(filename)
image = rgb2gray(imagefromfile)

global_thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
binary_global = image > global_thresh

block_size = 35
local_thresh = threshold_local(image, block_size, offset=10)
binary_local = image > local_thresh

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(7, 8))
ax = axes.ravel()
plt.gray()

ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].set_title('Original')

ax[1].imshow(binary_global)
ax[1].set_title('Global thresholding')

ax[2].imshow(binary_local)
ax[2].set_title('Local thresholding')

for a in ax:
    a.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load the `lenna.png` and print its shape you will see it is a 4-channel RGBA image rather than a 3-channel RGB image.

```
print mypic.shape
(512, 512, 4)
```

I am not sure which parts of your code apply to which image, so I am not sure where to go next, but I guess you want to just get the RGB part and discard the alpha:

```
RGB = mypic[...,:3]
```

Comment: Strangely ,  `shape` gives me  `[512 512 3]`  and  `dtype` gives me `uint8`.  After conversion to grayscale using `rg2gray` the `shape` changes to `[512 512]` .  All the values in the gray scale are between 0 and 1. I re-scaled to 255 and then I was able to get the regional thresholding to work.

Comment: The function `rgb2gray` seems to be exhibiting a different behavior for images loaded from `data.page()` when compared with the Lenna image loaded using `imread`.  The Lenna image is normalized , whereas the the former is not.